# Error -- SQL Compilation Error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'INNER'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to perform an inner join on two tables by date and county ID. Whenever I run the query, I get the following error:

```
SQL Compilation Error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'INNER'
```

The code is as follows:

```
SELECT  
     ISO3166_1,
     FIPS,
     DATE,
     CASES
FROM
     "covid-19","public"."timeseries"
WHERE
     ISO3166_1 = 'US'
INNER JOIN
     "db"."population_schema"."pop_table"
ON
      (("covid-19","public"."timeseries".fips = "db"."population_schema"."pop_table".fips)
AND
      ("covid-19","public"."timeseries".date= "db"."population_schema"."pop_table".date))
```

For reference, the date and FIPS data types are the same. Are there any glaringly obvious issues?

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clauses go after all JOINS:

```
SELECT  
     ISO3166_1,
     FIPS,
     DATE,
     CASES
FROM "covid-19","public"."timeseries" AS a
INNER JOIN "db"."population_schema"."pop_table" AS b
    ON a.fips = b.fips
        AND a.date= b.date
WHERE
    ISO3166_1 = 'US'
```

and if you alias those two tables, your join logic can be much more readable.

Comment: I tried this, including the alias, and now I am getting an error stating:                                              SQL Compliation error ambiguous column name.                                                                                     It looks like an issue that should be solved with aliasing but that's not working. Is there something else in the code that could throw  this error?

Comment: This means one of the named columns is in two or more tables/sources. Thus why a small alias is helpful because every column should be explicitly name x.column to avoid this.